# Cross Browser JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a simple cross browser javascript where I have added two generic click event; add and remove.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="normal">
            <p>This is  Paragraph No.1</p>
            <p>This is  Paragraph No.2</p>
            <p>This is  Paragraph No.3</p>
            <p>This is  Paragraph No.4</p>
            <p>This is  Paragraph No.5</p>
                <div id="divPara" style="color: #0094ff">
                    <p id="para">This is Paragraph Inside div para</p>
                 </div>
        </div>
        <div id="box">
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="normal" style="background-color: #ff6a00  " />
        <input type="button" value="change"  style="background-color: #aeef0d" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/CrossBrowser.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Event.js"></script>
```

**Event.js**

```
(function () {


    var warn = function () {
        alert("Button Clicked");
    };

    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i = i + 1) {
        eventUtility.addEvent(buttons[i], "click", warn);

    }

} ());
```

**CrossBrowser.js**

```
var eventUtility = function () {

    addEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (typeof addEventListener !== "undefined") {
            el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (attachEvent !== "undefined") {
            el.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = fn;
        }


    }

    removeEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (typeof removeEventListener != null) {
            el.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (typeof detachEvent != null) {
            el.detachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = fn;
        }



    }




};
```

Problem is that my button click event are not get fired on clicking?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `eventUtility` should just be an object.  What you have now is not declared properly and probably shows an error in the console (which is always the first place you should look when something isn't working).

You can declare it as a simple object like this:

```
var eventUtility = {
    addEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (el.addEventListener) {
            el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (el.attachEvent) {
            el.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = fn;
        }
    },

    removeEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (el.removeEventListener) {
            el.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (el.detachEvent) {
            el.detachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = fn;
        }
    }
};
```

P.S.  Do you really want to support versions of IE before IE6 that don't have `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()`.  I rather doubt it.  I think you can remove that last branch of each conditional.

Answer (score 0):

if you are taking the trouble of using typeof you should do it right

```
if(typeof el.addEventListener === 'function'){
    //add event handler
}
else if(typeof el.attachEvent === 'function'){
    //other way
}
else{
    //default
}
```

Comment: No real reason to use `typeof` at all here.  Can just check to see if the property exists at all.

Comment: you could, but that doesn't mean that if exists it actually does what you want to do, libraries don't live in isolation, they have to coexist with other libraries and there is no way you can guaranteed that someone didin't add a property named that way, your best bet is to test as much as possible. and yes you can just check  el["whatever"] but since he was using type of i just suggested him to use it right.

Comment: If someone has added `addEventListener` in an incompatible way (e.g. it's present, but not a function), then this is the least of your troubles.  You will need to root out the 3rd party library that is doing that and banish it from your project.  Taken right from the jQuery source `if (elem.addEventListener) {...}`.  I think jQuery's method here has been well vetted enough that you don't have to add extra code to your project beyond it.  Yes, if you were going to bother to use `typeof`, then may as well see if it's a function.  Just no need for `typeof`.